# How to apply mouseenter/mouseleave on multiple paired divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, jquery-hover

I'm trying to hover on div and affect another. Took a shot at it but my code is a bit clunky. Is there a shorter and better way to do this? This is the short version of the code, I need to apply this 70 more times.

```js
// hover and highlight corresponding box
$("#txt01").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('#txt01').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
        $('#img01').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('#txt01').css('border-color', '#0099ff');
        $('#img01').css('border-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
$("#txt02").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('#txt02').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
        $('#img02').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('#txt02').css('border-color', '#0099ff');
        $('#img02').css('border-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
$("#txt03").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('#txt03').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
        $('#img03').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('#txt03').css('border-color', '#0099ff');
        $('#img03').css('border-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have an example of **working code** that you are asking if there is a way to make it better, then this question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com , not Stack Overflow.

Comment: need html code that goes with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't using classes, which in this case I highly recommend, you can use ^ next to the ID to get any id starting with txt.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=txt]").on("mouseover", function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).prop("id").replace("txt", "");
    $('#txt' + id).css('border-color', '#cc0000');
    $('#img' + id).css('border-color', '#cc0000');
  });

  $("[id^=txt]").on("mouseout", function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).prop("id").replace("txt", "");
    $('#txt' + id).css('border-color', '#0099ff');
    $('#img' + id).css('border-color', 'transparent');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txt01">10</div>
<div id="img01">01</div>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone who replied and helped me, all your codes worked perfect! I chose this one as it's the simplest and shorter. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
mouseenter: function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("txt","");
    $('#txt'+id).css('border-color', '#cc0000');
    $('#img'+id).css('border-color', '#cc0000');
}
```

This will remove the `txt` part from the clicked id, so we only have the number left. That we can use then to select the correct corresponding id.

```js
// hover and highlight corresponding box
$("[id^=txt]").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("txt","");
        $('#txt'+id).css('border-color', '#cc0000');
        $('#img'+id).css('border-color', '#cc0000');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("txt","");
        $('#txt'+id).css('border-color', '#0099ff');
        $('#img'+id).css('border-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over with a for-loop. Because perhapse not all elements are existing test if the element exists before I add an eventhandler for it `if (elemTxt) { ... }`. 
**Remark:** The id can be build for this dynamical. Because you have 01-09 and the iterator i is only 1 digit I add for this first a string "0", add than the value and at last take only the last 2 chars from it.

```js
for (let i=1; i<=70; i++) {
    let nr = ('0'+i).slice(-2);
    let elemTxt = $('#txt'+nr);
    let elemImg = $('#img'+nr);
    if (elemTxt) {
        elemTxt.on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                elemTxt.css('border-color', '#cc0000');
                elemImg.css('border-color', '#cc0000');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                elemTxt.css('border-color', '#0099ff');
                elemImg.css('border-color', 'transparent');
            }
       });
    }   
}
```

```css
div, img { border: 1px solid red;}
img { height: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='txt01'>Text 1</div>
<img id='img01' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQIh1GvRa2-oH61PWTO_BA6aX6_BskpEIPkKA&usqp=CAU'>
<div id='txt02'>Text 1</div>
<img id='img02' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQIh1GvRa2-oH61PWTO_BA6aX6_BskpEIPkKA&usqp=CAU'>
<div id='txt50'>Text 1</div>
<img id='img50' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQIh1GvRa2-oH61PWTO_BA6aX6_BskpEIPkKA&usqp=CAU'>
```